# Customize authlogic error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I recently switched from restful_authentication to authlogic for authenticating users for my application. I've been exploring the API, and I've found a helper for generalizing error messages and overriding the message with my own, but I was curious as to how you can remove these two lines:

> 1 error prohibited this user session
>   from being saved
>
> There were problems with the following
>   fields:

Without messing around with the authlogic gem code, if possible. (Preferably without overriding error_messages_for)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message are default message of error_messages_for.

If you want change it, you can change the phrase in your en.yml file. with keys :

```
  errors:
    template:
      header:
        one: "Impossible d'enregistrer ce {{model}} : 1 erreur"
        other: "Impossible d'enregistrer ce {{model}} : {{count}} erreurs"
      body: "Veuillez vérifier les champs suivants : "
```

You can create a specific FormBuilder too for that. There are a guides about that in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html chapter 6